# How do I use the HTMLUnit driver with Selenium from Python?

Tags: python, selenium-rc, htmlunit, selenium-webdriver

How do I tell Selenium to use HTMLUnit?

I'm running selenium-server-standalone-2.0b1.jar as a Selenium server in the background, and the latest Python bindings installed with "pip install -U selenium".

Everything works fine with Firefox. But I'd like to use HTMLUnit, as it is lighter weight and doesn't need X. This is my attempt to do so:

```
>>> import selenium
>>> s = selenium.selenium("localhost", 4444, "*htmlunit", "http://localhost/")
>>> s.start()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/selenium/selenium/selenium.py", line 189, in start
    result = self.get_string("getNewBrowserSession", start_args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/selenium/selenium/selenium.py", line 223, in get_string
    result = self.do_command(verb, args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/selenium/selenium/selenium.py", line 217, in do_command
    raise Exception, data
Exception: Failed to start new browser session: Browser not supported: *htmlunit

Supported browsers include:
  *firefox
  *mock
  *firefoxproxy
  *pifirefox
  *chrome
  *iexploreproxy
  *iexplore
  *firefox3
  *safariproxy
  *googlechrome
  *konqueror
  *firefox2
  *safari
  *piiexplore
  *firefoxchrome
  *opera
  *iehta
  *custom
```

So the question is, what is the HTMLUnit driver called? How do I enable it?

The code for HTMLUnit seems to be in the source for Selenium 2, so I expected it to be available by default like the other browsers. I can't find any instructions on how to enable it.

Comment: I've tagged this with selenium-rc as well, as I don't mind whether I use Selenium 2 or Selenium-RC.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I use the HtmlUnit driver with Selenium through the Python bindings?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4081724/how-do-i-use-the-htmlunit-driver-with-selenium-through-the-python-bindings)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

using the selenium 2.20.0.jar server and matching python version, I am able to use HtmlUnitDriver by specifying the browser as *mock

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities

server_url = "http://%s:%s/wd/hub" % (test_host, test_port)
dc = DesiredCapabilities.HTMLUNIT
wd = webdriver.Remote(server_url, dc)
wd.get('http://www.google.com')
```

Answer (score 16):

As of the 2.0b3 release of the python client you can create an HTMLUnit webdriver via a remote connection like so:

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Remote(
  desired_capabilities=webdriver.DesiredCapabilities.HTMLUNIT)
driver.get('http://www.google.com')
```

You can also use the `HTMLUNITWITHJS` capability item for a browser with Javascript support.

Note that you need to run the Selenium Java server for this to work, since HTMLUnit is implemented on the Java side.

Comment: I run selenium-server-standalone-3.141.59, but it doesn't work!

Comment: @ghanem This answer is from 2011, you probably need to find a more recent solution

Answer (score 2):

I use it like this:

```
from selenium.remote import connect                                                                                                                          

b = connect('htmlunit')                                                                                                                                      
b.get('http://google.com')                                                                                                                                   

q = b.find_element_by_name('q')                                                                                                                              
q.send_keys('selenium')                                                                                                                                      
q.submit()                                                                                                                                                   

for l in b.find_elements_by_xpath('//h3/a'):                                                                                                                 
    print('%s\n\t%s\n' % (l.get_text(), l.get_attribute('href')))
```

Comment: Where are any way to provide Selenium 1 interface by HtmlUnit ?