# Python webrowser emulator with executing javascript

Tags: python, selenium

Recently time, i must write bots for some sites (registration, posting and parsing). I do this with  [grablib](http://grablib.org), but now, i must write bot for site on JS. I see many variants such as Selenium and forks*?* of it.

But I need multithreading, and, as I understood, Selenium opens a browser and I do not need. I have to work in the 80-120 flows on Linux server.

Which tool I choose and what to read? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Selenium /can/ use a browser, but can also use HTMLUnit as a backend. This question has some good info: [How do I use the HTMLUnit driver with Selenium from Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4618373/how-do-i-use-the-htmlunit-driver-with-selenium-from-python)

Answer (score 1):

There is a Browser called [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/) which may serve your needs.