# How to set up HTMLUnit Driver with selenium in python?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, htmlunit, htmlunit-driver

Reading the answers on here has led me to understand that I need to connect to the Selenium Java server because HTMLUnit is implemented in java. I don't really understand what this means and would appreciate if someone would point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

use the selenium jar below 2.52 which come inbuilt in the selenium

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Remote(
desired_capabilities=webdriver.DesiredCapabilities.HTMLUNIT)
driver.get('https://stackoverflow.com/')
```

above 2.53 you have to download the `HTMLdriver` separately

For more information visit this [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4618373/how-do-i-use-the-htmlunit-driver-with-selenium-from-python/5518175#5518175)